# JTable not showing in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm new to java..I want to show a table in my GUI. I know there are several questions like this but that didn't help me. Any help would be appreciated.

**Test.java**

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


    class Test {

        JFrame frame;
        JTable table;
        Container pane;

        public void initGUI () {
            frame = new JFrame("Table");
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            pane = frame.getContentPane();

            Object[][] rows = {
                {"Amir", "Karachi"},
                {"Noman", "Quetta"},
                {"Salman", "Rawalpindi"}
            };
            Object[] cols = {"Name", "City"};

            table = new JTable(rows, cols);
            pane.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

        public static void main (String args[]) {
            Test obj = new Test();
            obj.initGUI();
        }

    }
```

Comment: you forgot to display the 'frame' `frame.setVisible(true);`. you might also want to set its size to something useful, or use `frame.pack()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

Don't use a null layout.

Because you don't use a layout manager the size of the scrollpane is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Leave the default layout manager of the frame as the BorderLayout.

Also, a frame should be made visible AFTER all components have been added to the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for working examples to get you started. Use the structure of the code found in the tutorials and then modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Except `frame.setLayout(null);` you can exclude `getContentPane();`. Here is worked one:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Test {

    JFrame frame;
    JTable table;
    Container pane;

    public void initGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Table");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Object[][] rows = {
            {"Amir", "Karachi"},
            {"Noman", "Quetta"},
            {"Salman", "Rawalpindi"}
        };
        Object[] cols = {"Name", "City"};

        table = new JTable(rows, cols);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test obj = new Test();
        obj.initGUI();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about using getContent() pane. It is not necessary as you can directly add components to the frame, but it will not cause a problem if you add the components to the content pane.

Comment: And the suggestion to not use a null layout was already given so there is no need to clutter the forum with the same suggestion.

Comment: I check the code concurrently, I didn't use your answer, and I am going to up your answer, because it's correct